# how to pick lines in three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js

Is there a way to pick lines in threeJS?
I checked by changing a bit this demo http://mrdoob.github.io/three.js/examples/webgl_interactive_cubes.html to remplace cubes with lines and it seems not to be picking anything: http://jsfiddle.net/p3cdk/

```
var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0));
geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(20, 20, 20));
```

The ray casting system doesn't mention lines at all: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/core/Raycaster.js
(and I suppose the ray casting system must give an interesting behavior in wireframe).

I'm not an expert in 3D stuff, but it seems difficult for me to pick a line with a ray, I'd rather cast a cone, or do something with the pixel buffer, but I have no clue on how to achieve that.

My context is CAD, hence heavily stylized systems, orthographic cameras and pure lines.

Answer (score 2):

use a selection box like in autocad.

if you drag left to right the box is blue, and it select objects completely contained in the box.

if you drag right to left the box is green and it selects anything the box is touching.

your 'pickbox size' is the size of the box in your crosshairs

when you click, its basically using the pickbox as a selection box and selecting anything touching. on my program i removed the cursor image and displayed the crosshairs directly on the canvas so users with accessibility option won't have problems.

sorry i just saw this i know you posted 7 months ago, but i know what im talking about and figured it might help someone, if not you